# patch CyanogenMod 13 against KRACK on samsung s5 (klte)

Tags: android, cyanogenmod, wpa

I am a very happy user of [CyanogenMod 13](https://androidjungles.com/cm13-install-cyanogenmod-13-android-phones/) (stable) on a Samsung S5 (klte) for months. It is a very stable rom based on Android Marshmallow but I'd like to patch my phone against the newly discovered KRACK flaw.

CyanogenMod is now LineageOS which only offers a nightly version of Android Nougat which I don't need. Also, I have had buggy experiences with nightly builds in the past so I'd really want to stick with my current stable rom.

Is there a way I can patch my rom against KRACK without upgrading? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to Android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi, max! I would suggest you look into the information available on the official website of the KRACK vulnerability research. I have a [set of links](https://rafikitechnology.com/2017/10/16/wi-fi-protected-access-ii-wpa2-vulnerability/) on my blog too for places you can go for answers. The KRACK vulnerability site is on the blog as well.

Comment: Joril, sorry I didn't even know the existence of android.stackexchange.com
@Alain, I just visited the your sites but I can't find the update the CyanogenMod13. What I am looking for is just an updated version of the packaged involved (wpa_supplicant + others maybe?)

Comment: @max, Have you had a chance to look here on the [CyanogenMod Github](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_wpa_supplicant) as well? Thanks and sorry it's been so long. Hopefully you have solved your problem by now.